# cannot get the variable value from main.c

Tags: c

I'm new to C language.

In my **main.c**

```
float BatteryLvl_Volts;

float get_BatteryLvl_Volts(void)
{
    return BatteryLvl_Volts;
}
```

In my **Battery.c**

```
float BatteryLvl_Volts = get_BatteryLvl_Volts();

void battery_level_indicator(float BatteryLvl_Volts)
{
    if( 3.3 < BatteryLvl_Volts ){
        LED_ON(GREEN);       // Turn on Green LED
    }
}
```

**My Question**

If I use **#include "main.c"** in **Battery.c**, the IDE will give a lot of warnings (more than 200). How to solve this issue, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you including one source file in another? And why are you defining a global variable with the same name in both files?

Comment: You also can't initialize a global variable with the result of a function like you're trying... Maybe start with a decent C tutorial to learn the basics of the language before doing anything fancy?

Comment: Rather than warning, have you tried compiling it?

Comment: You don't want to include `.c` files.  Instead, include the corresponding `.h` file.  A `.h` file contains all of the external declarations needed to call functions and access variables that are part of the interface to that module.  The implementation resides in the corresponding `.c` file.  The `.c` file gets compiled once, and is linked into the program.  The `.h` file, on the other hand, is included by as many other files as needed, enabling them to reference the declared items.

Comment: In your case, your `.h` file would contain the declaration of `get_BatteryLvl_Volts`, but not the function definition.  The `.c` file would contain the function definition, i.e. the function body.

Comment: The compiler issues the warnings, not the IDE.  The IDE merely _presents_ the warnings.  This code fragment has issues besides how to access a common instance of `BatteryLvl_Volts` you would do well to clean up the code so that it presents only the issue of interest.  It certainly seems to lack cohesion and increases coupling to have two battery related functions in separate sources.

Answer (score 2):

To access a variable *defined* in one translation unit (file1.c) in another (file2.c), the symbol must be *declared* `extern`:

```
// file1.c
float some_global_float = 0.0 ;
```

```
// file2.c
extern float some_global_float ;
```

Normally you'd put the extern declaration in a header to avoid repetition and to allow the compiler to check the declaration and definition match:

```
// file1.c
#include "file1.h"
float some_global_float = 0.0 ;
```

```
// file1.h
#if !define FILE2_H
#define FILE2_H
    extern float some_global_float ;
#endif
```

```
// file2.c
#include "file1.h"

float some_function( float a )
{
    return some_global_float * a ;
}
```

Now all that said, you should in fact really avoid global variables altogether.  It is bad practice and invariably unnecessary.  But that is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial site for C: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/index.htm

You should name files which will be `#include` into a C file with suffix `.h` (header file). Header files should just be definitions or static libraries and no actual program code.

If you want to combine multiple C files you use a so called linker. A linker is a program which combines multiple binaries into one binary.

If you want to access a global variable you need to use the keyword `extern`.

`main.c`

```
extern int g_bananas = 0; // declaration and definition - extern is optional
//int g_bananas = 0; // this would be also fine for declaration and definition

void calcbananas(int a, int b); // just declaration - optional but recommended

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    calcbananas(1, 2);
    return g_bananas;
}
```

`sub.c`

```
extern int g_bananas; // just declaration - extern is needed

void calcbananas(int a, int b){
    g_bananas = a + b;
}
```

`main.c` and `sub.c` need to be linked by a linker program.

PS you should always use a prefix for naming global variables, like `g_`

PPS some compilers have built-in linker, for example the gcc compiler may compile and link above 2 C files just by typing shell command `gcc main.c sub.c`